# Add a graphic interface (Tkinter) to this programm in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I just wrote a program in Python. The program does what follows:

There is a class called original. It has 2 methods (a part of **init**). The first method is code. What "code" does is receive a string and encode it changing every character from the received string for another character of the ASCII table. This ASCII character depends of the function generacion_clave. The function generacion_clave generates randomly a number between 1 and k (k is an input parameter for this function).

For example the character "e" is in the place 101 on the ASCII table. So if the generated number is 8, the character e is changed for the character in the ASCII table which has the position 109 (101 + 8)

The method decode receives the encoded string and the clave, and it returns the decoded string.

What I would like to do is add to the program a graphic interface that contains:

An entry box for the original String, A Canvas (or a output box?) where the encoded and decoded string will we shown, a button to encode and a button to decode.

I am quite new in Python, I have read some tutorials about Tkinter but I don´t find it easy at all. So I would appreciate any help :)

```
from random import randint 

class original():

def __init__(self, mensaje_original):
    self.mensaje_original = mensaje_original


def code(self, gen_clav, *args):
    cadena_codificada ="" 
    clave = gen_clav(*args) 
    for i in self.mensaje_original:
        clave_mod = ord(i) + clave
        if clave_mod > 255:
            clave_mod = clave_mod - 255

        cadena_codificada = cadena_codificada + chr(clave_mod)

    return cadena_codificada, clave    

def decode(self, cadena_cod_clave):
    cadena_decodificada =""
    clave = int(cadena_cod_clave[1])
    for i in cadena_cod_clave[0]:
        clave_mod = ord(i) - clave
        if clave_mod > 255:
            clave_mod = clave_mod - 255
        cadena_decodificada = cadena_decodificada + chr(clave_mod)          

    return cadena_decodificada, cadena_cod_clave[1]     

def generacion_clave(k):
cl = randint(1, k + 1)
return cl


mensaje_original = "Hola tio como estas"   
mensaje = original(mensaje_original)
cad_cod_clav = mensaje.code(generacion_clave, 10)


cad_dec_clav = mensaje.decode(cad_cod_clav)
print "La cadena original es: %s" %cad_dec_clav[0]   
print "La cadena cifrada es: %s" %cad_cod_clav[0]
print "la clave es: %d " %cad_cod_clav[1]
```

Thanks a lot in advance!
Pablo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this is not a free code writing service, so you really should try implementing this yourself. If you get stuck anywhere during implementation, you can ask a specific [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Building GUI with Tk is not that difficult.

You'll need an Entry (Widget for input), a set of Labels(For printing the output) and a Button.

Building the main frame and using the entry widget is mentioned here. http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

I'd suggest you give a basic gui a try (maybe in a separate file), and we'll link them after the GUI is completed.

If you need, I'll help you with the linking after a basic GUI is created.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to do it. I start only adding 2 buttons (Encode and Quit). Encode should call to the method encode in the class original and Quit should close the window (which works). Does anybody know why the Encode button doesn't work?

```
from random import randint 
from Tkinter import *


class original():

def __init__(self, mensaje_original):
    self.mensaje_original = mensaje_original


def code(self, gen_clav, *args):
    cadena_codificada ="" 
    clave = gen_clav(*args) 
    for i in self.mensaje_original:
        clave_mod = ord(i) + clave
        if clave_mod > 255:
            clave_mod = clave_mod - 255

        cadena_codificada = cadena_codificada + chr(clave_mod)
    print  cadena_codificada, clave   
    return cadena_codificada, clave    

def decode(self, cadena_cod_clave):
    cadena_decodificada =""
    clave = int(cadena_cod_clave[1])
    for i in cadena_cod_clave[0]:
        clave_mod = ord(i) - clave
        if clave_mod > 255:
            clave_mod = clave_mod - 255
        cadena_decodificada = cadena_decodificada + chr(clave_mod)          

    return cadena_decodificada, cadena_cod_clave[1]     

def generacion_clave(k):
    cl = randint(1, k + 1)
    return cl


class graficos:

    def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.encode_buttom = Button(frame, text = "Encode!", command = self.printMessage)
    self.encode_buttom.pack(side = LEFT)

    self.quit_buttom = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
    self.quit_buttom.pack(side = LEFT)

def printMessage(self):
    mensaje_original = "Hola tio como estas"   
    mensaje = self.original(mensaje_original)
    print mensaje



root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x250")

b = graficos(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot. 
Regards
Pablo

Comment: Some parts of the code should be moved to the right direction. I just copied uncorrectly, but I think it is clear enough. Thanks again

Comment: please don't extend your question in the answer section. The answer section is strictly for answers to your question. You can edit your original question if you have additional information to add.